# Unable to compile the GWT module while trying to use javax.annotation.Nullable?

Tags: java, gwt

I would like to use the `javax.annotation.Nullable` annotation in my GWT project. I would like to know which module has to be inherited into my gwt.xml file inorder to use that annotation. The google guava jar internally uses the Nullable annotation and If I use that Jar in my project it is able to compile. Please help me what package has to be inherited inorder to use the `javax.annotation.Nullable` annotation?

I have been searching on net for long time, but still unable to figure out which package has to be inherited.

Any suggestions would be appretiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a dependency on JSR 305. For example, Guava uses this:

```
<groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
<artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
<version>1.3.9</version>
```

Now, you have to use a workaround mentioned [in a issue](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=776#c42):

1. Create a simple `javax/annotation/Annotation.gwt.xml` file in your project:

   ```
   <module>
       <source path="" />
   </module>
   ```
2. Add `<inherits name='javax.annotation.Annotation' />` to your applications module (`.gwt.xml`) file.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response. I am able to compile my code.